# i tried to calculate the sum of numbers between 1 and the inputted numer

Tags: c++, numbers, c++17

The program demonstrates the operation of the loop operator.
Calculation of the sum of natural numbers. The positive integer n is introduced. The sum of natural numbers from 1 to n (inclusive) is calculated.
Check n for validity.
that was the work that I was given and I still don't know how to accomplish it and this is where  left off:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
    std::cout << sum << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i += 2` -- Why are you incrementing the loop index by 2?

Comment: A little `std::cout << i << std::endl;` inside the loop would help you see te problem.

Comment: I tried different stuff but it didn't work , so I don't know what to write in there

Comment: `The natural numbers from 1 to n` That means the number increases by one each time, that way you get all the natural numbers (instead of just half of them like you are getting at the moment). So `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 1)` or (same thing) `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`

Comment: 'I tried different stuff but it didn't work' Probably you tried the obvious thing first, and when it didn't work you concluded wrongly that the obvious thing was incorrect, and so you tried stuff that was obviously incorrect (like `i += 2`). There are many reasons that a program goes wrong, so don't assume that when it goes wrong you are trying the wrong thing, you could be trying the right thing, but just making some silly error somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anatomy of the `for` loop goes as this:
`for(1;2;3)`

1. What you do when entering the loop. In this case, setting `i = 1`.
2. The loop's end condition. You seem to be getting this right as well.
3. An operation to do every iteration of the loop. In your case, `i += 2` will make `i` look like this on each iteration: `1 3 5 7 ... n`. Get it? Because you are incrementing it by 2.

The mathematical operation you intend to do looks like this: `sum = 1+2+3+...+n`. To achieve this, you only need to adjust the 3rd part of the `for` loop.
One way to check what is going on inside the loop instead of just guessing it is "probing" the variables in it, like @molbdnilo proposed, by adding something like `std::cout << i << std::endl;` inside the loop.

Hope this helps you find your solution.